# Reduce size of Video Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, media

I am using the Xamarin.Media plugin which works great, but I have stumbled upon an issue when trying to pick a video. It looks like it is not supported to decrease the size of this video as it is with when u take a video / or take / pick a photo.
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

So if i pick a photo i can do:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
{
      PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small
});
```

But picking a video does not support a media option, so i have to do:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();
```

So my question is, how do I compress a video `MediaFile` or `Stream` so it is reduces the size of the file and quality?

Comment: You have to achieve it in different plantforms, for IOS, you can refer to this link: https://thestackunderflowblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/xamarin-tips-and-tricks-compressing-videos-in-xamarin-forms-projects/ Or you can refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992574/10627299

Comment: https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/index.html is this the package u need for android to accomplish this? `FFMpeg` cannot be found so i assume i need a package

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/au6hegl5jztjhn0/XamarinAndroidFFmpeg.dll?dl=0  this .dll file

Comment: code runs, but sizing seems to be uneffected

Comment: issue is the output path, i try to use the new path i make, but throws an exception when trying to get a thumbnail from it `
                    retriever.SetDataSource(urlVideo);`, works well with the raw file

Comment: [MediaMetadataRetriever] setDataSource - FileNotFoundException

Comment: Please make sure your file path and permission correctly. Note: If you running your application in Android 10, you should add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.